# Create a sharepoint groups does not work, index out of range

Tags: 2013, development

The following code has been tested in dev, test environments and it works perfect.

However when I run it on qa environment I get the following exception:

```
SecurityManager.CreateMembersMAGroupForSubsitesIfNotExists(entityWeb.Url,opportunity.OpportunityCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


/// <summary>
        /// Creates the sharepoint group Members MA, for Manager Assistants for job and opportunitysites.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="weburl">Web site url</param>
        /// <param name="groupPrefix">Group prefix</param>
        public static void CreateMembersMAGroupForSubsitesIfNotExists(string weburl, string groupPrefix)
        {
            LoggingService.LogInfo(LoggingCategory.Security, String.Format("Starting  CreateMembersMAGroupForSubsitesIfNotExists: {0}", weburl));
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {

                        using (var site = new SPSite(weburl))
                        {
                            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                LoggingService.LogInfo(LoggingCategory.Security,String.Format("Creating member MA group for web: {0}", web.Name));
                                //Create custom members ma group if it doesnt exist
                                if (!SecurityHelper.GroupExists(web.SiteGroups, String.Concat(groupPrefix, " ",Constants.ContentTypes.System.SecurityMapping.MASPGroup)))
                                {
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    web.SiteGroups.Add(String.Concat(groupPrefix, " ",Constants.ContentTypes.System.SecurityMapping.MASPGroup),web.SiteAdministrators[0], null, String.Empty);
                                    var maGroupCreated =web.SiteGroups[String.Concat(groupPrefix, " ",Constants.ContentTypes.System.SecurityMapping.MASPGroup)];
                                    var roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(maGroupCreated);
                                    var roleDefBindings = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;
                                    var roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute Share"];
                                    roleDefBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                                    web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                                    roleDefinition.Update();
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                    LoggingService.LogInfo(LoggingCategory.Security,String.Format("Created member MA group for web: {0}", web.Name));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    LoggingService.LogInfo(LoggingCategory.Security, String.Format("Group default member ma already existed: {0},{1}", web.Name, groupPrefix));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingService.LogError(LoggingCategory.Security, ex, String.Format("Creating members MA group for web failed: {0}", weburl));
            }

            LoggingService.LogInfo(LoggingCategory.Security, String.Format("Finished  CreateMembersMAGroupForSubsitesIfNotExists: {0}", weburl));

        }




 /// <summary>
        /// Group exists by name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="groups"></param>
        /// <param name="name"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool GroupExists(SPGroupCollection groups, string name)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ||
                (name.Length > 255) ||
                (groups == null) ||
                (groups.Count == 0))
                return false;
            return (groups.GetCollection(new String[] { name }).Count > 0);
        }
```

> (Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.)
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)      at
>   xx.SP.DMS.Common.Helpers.SecurityManager.<>c_*DisplayClass23.b*_21()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)      at
>   xx.xx.DMS.Common.Helpers.SecurityManager.CreateCustomVisitorsGroupForSubsitesIfNotExists(String
>   weburl, String groupPrefix)

The only thing I can think of is web.SiteAdministrator[0],? or any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the QA environment, the site collection administrator was empty, :(, dont know why, but then it works. Lesson learned

Comment: Hi! Can you please add more details to this post? How did you check it was empty, and so on. Makes it more helpful to future readers

Comment: Site ssettings -> Site collection administrators, I dont know why,but it was empty, and that was the cause the code was not working. after I added a user there, then it works again